# Optomizing Django API Queries to reduce database hits

Tags: django

This is just on my belief that Django has unlimited possibilities. I have an API, testing it with debug-toolbar, I have up to 13 hits per request.
[image]

I would like to think there is something I can do to bring down the database hits to 1.
Here is my API List View:

```
class ProductsListAPIView(ListAPIView):
    queryset = Product.objects.active()
    serializer_class = ProductSerializer
    filter_backends = [SearchFilter, OrderingFilter]
    permission_classes = [HasAPIKey | AllowAny]
    search_fields = ['product_title', 'product_description',
                     'user__first_name', 'product_type', 'product_price', 'product_city']
    pagination_class = ProductPageNumberPagination


    def get_serializer_context(self, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super(ProductsListAPIView, self).get_serializer_context(*args, **kwargs)
        context['request'] = self.request
        coordinates = self.request.GET.get("coordinates")
        if not coordinates or len(coordinates) <= 4:
            coordinates = '0.0,0.0'
        context['coordinates'] = coordinates
        return context

    def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):

        query = self.request.GET.get("search")
        lookups = ()

        if query and len(query) > 0:
            queryArray = query.split()
            for q in queryArray:
                lookups = (Q(product_title__icontains=q) |
                           Q(product_description__icontains=q) |
                           Q(product_type__icontains=q) |
                           Q(product_city__icontains=q) |
                           Q(user__first_name__icontains=q) |
                           Q(user__last_name__icontains=q) |
                           Q(product_address__icontains=query)
                           )
        # If user is loggedIn and discovery range / point and address is set
        # Returns products just in that range.
        uid = self.request.GET.get("uid")
        queryset_list = self.queryset
        if uid and len(uid) > 5:
            try:
                user = CustomUser.objects.get(uid=uid)
                from django.contrib.gis.measure import D
                if user is not None and user.point is not None and len(user.address) > 5:
                    if query and len(query) > 0:
                        print('USER RANGE and SEARCH QUERY!')
                        query_of_set = queryset_list.filter(
                            point__distance_lte=(user.point, D(km=user.discovery_range))).filter(lookups).distinct(
                        )

                    else:
                        print('USER RANGE WITHOUT SEARCH QUERY!')

                        query_of_set = queryset_list.filter(
                            point__distance_lte=(user.point, D(km=user.discovery_range)))

                    if query_of_set.count() < 3:
                        print('FEWER THAN EXPECTED NUMBER')
                        if query and len(query) > 0:
                            query_of_set = queryset_list.filter(lookups).distinct(
                            )
                        else:
                            query_of_set = queryset_list

                    queryset_list = query_of_set
            except Exception as e:

                queryset_list = queryset_list.filter(lookups).distinct(
                ) if query and len(query) > 0 else queryset_list
                print(f'USER ASSOCIATED QUERY EXCEPTION: {e}')
                logging.error(f'USER ASSOCIATED QUERY EXCEPTION: {e}')
        else:
            print('USER DETAILS NOT SET!, GIVE THEM A GENERAL VIEW')
            queryset_list = queryset_list.filter(lookups).distinct(
            ) if query and len(query) > 0 else queryset_list
        return queryset_list
```

What will be the suggestions to bring the database hit down especially for the CustomUser table? Is there any way I can do the products in range query, without first having to query the database for the user object. `user = CustomUser.objects.get(uid=uid)`?

And also for the count() for my queryset after the filter. I realize, using `query_of_set.count() < 3` adds a couple other database queries. Any other way to check here for the number of items in the queryset? I tried `len(query_of_set)` but it's basically the same result.

And yes, I have used `prefetch_related()` to get the product photos, comments and votes which all result in a one hit each. I guess there's no other way out for that.

Comment: what about select_related?

Comment: @RoksolankaFedkovych has been used where possible.

Comment: could you please also add you models like product and user for a better understanding of db structure?